# itextsharp - PDF's - What version of Adobe Reader are these supposed to be compatible with?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I've generated some PDFs with iTextSharp. I've had some end-users complain about compatibility issues.

Is there specific version that iTextSharp targets for PDF compatibility?

Trying to figure out what to do about this issue with some end-users not being about to view the PDFs.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read somewhere (can't find the forum message right now) that if you use encryption in iTextSharp you need at least Acrobat 7 to read it.

Also, set the PDF version as low as you can to maximize compatibility (with `SetPDFVersion()`)